# drupal wordpress - aspecific behaviour

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, drupal

- Drupal site live, all running well
- created subfolder "/blog" and installed wordpress there
- changed the rewrite rules in the .htaccess for drupal to ignore the /blog/ directory
- all is running fine if I got to site.com/blog
- I can edit and add and comment and all

**Question:**
if I, however, want to change the theme or anything else CSS related, I always get a blank screen, white, no errors or anything

I discovered these are about the only URL's with actual 'special' characters in them: e.g. *"customize.php?return=%2Fblog%2Fwp-admin%2Fthemes.php"*

What is going on here?

Comment: It is just funny that the questions you really would like to see answered, are not :-(